# Sheafification of a subpresheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a subpresheaf of a sheaf $\mathscr{H}$. If I understood correctly, in this case the sheafification has a particularly simple form. It is the sheaf defined by
$$\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}(U)=\{s\in \mathscr{H}(U)\:|\:s\text{ locally lies in }\mathscr{F}\},$$
where we say that $s\in \mathscr{H}(U)$ locally lies in $\mathscr{F}$ is there's an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $U$ such that $s|_{U_i}\in \mathscr{F}(U_i)$ for every $i$.

It is clear that this is indeed a sheaf but I can't see how it satisfies the universal property of the sheafification.

I thought about doing it in the following way: I really think that this construction is functorial in $\mathscr{F}$. Supposing that, given a morphism $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{G}$ we should have an induced morphism $\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}\to\widetilde{\mathscr{G}}$ which coincides with our original morphism when restricting to $\mathscr{F}$. If $\mathscr{G}$ is a sheaf, $\widetilde{\mathscr{G}}=\mathscr{G}$ and so this yields our desired morphism. But I can't really see why this construction is functorial in $\mathscr{F}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ and a morphism of presheaves $f:\mathscr{F}\to \mathscr{G}$, you can directly construct a morphism of presheaves (and therefore of sheavs) $\widetilde{f}:\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}\to \mathscr{G}$ that extends $f$. Given a section $s\in \widetilde{\mathscr{F}}(U)$, choose any open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $U$ such that the restrictions $s\mid_{U_i}$ lie in $\mathscr{F}$. Then you can apply $f$ to each of these restrictions, and glue their images to get $\widetilde{f}(s)\in \mathscr{G}(U)$. It is not hard to check that this is well-defined, i.e. independent of the open cover, and that in fact $\widetilde{f}$ is the unique extension of $f$. The latter shows that $\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}$ is a sheafification.

Regarding the functoriality you mention, since your definition requires choice of a sheaf $\mathscr{H}$, I am not sure how to make sense of this (of course you know after the fact that sheafification is functorial by the universal property).

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming $\mathscr H$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on a topological space $X$. 
Since $\mathscr H$ is a sheaf, by the universal property of sheafi-fication, the morphism of pre-sheaves $\iota:\mathscr F\hookrightarrow\tilde {\mathscr F} $ factors through $\mathscr F\xrightarrow{j}\mathscr F^{sh}\xrightarrow{\bar \iota }\tilde{\mathscr F}$. To see that $\bar \iota: \mathscr F^{sh}\rightarrow \tilde {\mathscr F}$ is an isomorphism, it is sufficient to check at the level of stalks. 
 Observe that at the level of stalks, we have for $x\in X$, the base space, the composition $$\mathscr F_x\xrightarrow{j_x}\mathscr F^{sh}_x\xrightarrow{\bar \iota_x }{\tilde{\mathscr F}}_x=\mathscr F_x $$ which is identity. Moreover, $j_x$ is an isomorphism. This comes from the very construction of the sheafification. Thus $\bar \iota_x$ is an isomorphism for every $x\in X$ and hence $\bar \iota $ is an isomorphism.

**Note:** The standard construction of $\mathscr F^{sh}$ is to consider $\mathscr F$ as a sub-presheaf of the sheaf of stalks $\mathscr H(U):=\{\prod_{x\in U}s_x: s_x\in \mathscr F_x \}$ and then look at $\tilde {\mathscr F}$ in this sheaf.

Comment: I would prefer an answer which does not suppose that the sheafification exists since I am trying to *use* what I've said to prove that the sheafification exists. My plan is to show that sheafification works as I've said when we have a subpresheaf of a sheaf and then reduce the general case to this one. (Using basically what you've said.)

Comment: Not every presheaf can be embedded in a sheaf, so you can’t use this to construct sheafification in general. Incidentally, presheaves that can be embedded in a sheaf are called separated.

Comment: @ZhenLin Surely, but there's a map from every presheaf $\mathscr{F}$ to the sheaf defined by $U\mapsto \prod_{p\in U}\mathscr{F}_p$. The sheafification (as I've constructed) of the image of this map is the sheafification of $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: In fact, that construction is correct. But the map $F \to \prod_p F_p$ is not always a monomorphism.

Comment: @ZhenLin, for sure. Do you know how to prove that my construction satisfies the universal property of sheafification without assuming that the sheafification exists in the first place?